# R Packrat Fails to load private library

Tags: r, centos7, rstudio-server

I have developed a solution using R and want to transfer it to the production server (CentOS 7) which has no Internet connection to install packages. To facilitate installation of packages, I used packrat to bundle the packages I used in my R script to the project.

Using packrat::bundle(), I have created a tar file of the project and moved the file to the server and untar the zip file.

According to a [post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-reproducible-software-environments-with-packrat/) in Blogger, once I open the project, `When R is started from that directory, Packrat will do its magic and make sure the software environment is the same as on the source machine.`

However, when I open the project in Server (using R-Studio Server 0.99), nothing happens and it throws error of unknown packages.

When manually execute the "packarat/init.R" file below error is thrown

> Error in ensurePackageSymlink(source, target) :
>
> Target '/home/R_Projects/prjName/packrat/lib-R/base' already exists and is not a symlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the problem and solve it. The symlink error is related to centOS (it is not related to R). I just simply removed all the folders inside the

> /home/R_Projects/prjName/packrat/lib-R

Because these folder exist, the packrat is unable to create symlink with the same name inside the lib-R folder. If I remove them, it will create a link (shortcut) to the actual folder where the r package is located.

Hope it helps future readers.

Comment: had the same problem on MacOS, when I had just enabled packrat and updated once. deleting the non-symlink and re-initialising the proj fixed it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: As @Ruben points out, it looks like this or a similar error can be observed on a few Operating Systems (I've seen it with Fedora too).  I've commented on this GitHub issue, looking for guidance: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/228#issuecomment-319855165